# Speed Up Nested For Loops?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, loops, nested

I have a bunch of loops which find the right words in a plist for me and filter them out. However, its so slow, there is about 2000 words total in the plist. See the code below, I need to speed this up, it causes about 2-3 second delays! Not sure how I can though.

The plist is made up for approximately 200 arrays, each with 10 words in. So I grab a dictionary of the plist, `dict`. Then go through all of those arrays until the find the words I need.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [lang1Words count]; i++)
    {        
        NSString *errorWordLang1 = [lang1Words objectAtIndex:i];

        for (NSArray *a in [dict allValues])
        {
            for (NSString *s in a)
            {
                if ([errorWordLang1 isEqualToString:s])
                {
                    NSArray *temp = [dict allKeysForObject:a];
                    NSString *originLang1ArrayKey = [temp objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSArray *lang1Temp = [self getWordsArrayForKey:originLang1ArrayKey];
                    NSInteger index = [lang1Temp indexOfObject:errorWordLang1];
                    NSString *originLang2ArrayKey;
                    if ([languageKey isEqualToString:@"Latin"]) originLang2ArrayKey = [originLang1ArrayKey stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Latin" withString:@"English"];
                    else if ([languageKey isEqualToString:@"English"]) originLang2ArrayKey = [originLang1ArrayKey stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"English" withString:@"Latin"];
                    NSArray *lang2Temp = [self getWordsArrayForKey:originLang2ArrayKey];
                    NSString *errorWordLang2 = [lang2Temp objectAtIndex:index];

                    if (errorWordLang2 == nil || errorWordLang1 == nil) break;

                    [orderedLang2Words addObject:errorWordLang2];
                    [orderedLang1Words addObject:errorWordLang1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It might help if you included a small part of that plist or dictionaries and tell what the expected result is.

Comment: A 2000 for loop shouldn't even make a dent in your CPU time.  Have you tried adding a NSLog before and after that section of code?

Comment: I don't see how that would help. Although all arrays are what i expect them to be. It might be 2000 words, but then I am doing it 10 times, `lang1Words` can be as high as 10.

Comment: how many languages are possible in the getWordsArrayForKey? If it is just two, i.e. Latin and English, then have separate arrays for each. This would reduce the creation of arrays in the inner loop when getWordsArrayForKey is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should profile with Instruments (the Time Profile instrument specifically), then post the saved profile and we can look at and offer advice. Optimizing without a profiler is like target shooting with a blindfold.